# Error al Guardar xml con caracteres especiales < > & ' " en proyecto vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo que guardar los caracteres especiales mencionados en el titulo sin embargo al guardarlos en el archivo cfdi xml, sí me los guarda pero en todos los casos siempre agrega
& y despues ' cuando debería de ser solamente ' de tal forma que el nombre quede así T'S VALLADOLID el nombre real es T'S VALLADOLID pero al guardarlo en el xml
me lo deja T&'S VALLADOLID y al timbrar el documento no lo reconoce sin embargo si manualmente edito el xml antes de enviarlo a timbrar y le elimino la frase &
si lo timbra sin problemas, el archivo lo guardo en utf-8, el código lo tengo en vs2008 aunque hice pruebas en el vs2022 y el detalle persiste.

Alguna idea de porque siempre guarda el xml anteponiendo & con los caracteres especiales, ya lo intenté con replace y tambien con SecurityElement.Escape y no le encuentro.

Anexo el ejemplo del código funcional que estoy utilizando.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim comprobante As cfdV40.Comprobante = New cfdV40.Comprobante()

    comprobante.Serie = "CFDI4I"
    comprobante.Folio = "1"
    comprobante.Version = "4.0"
    comprobante.Fecha = DateTime.Now
    comprobante.TipoDeComprobante = "I"
    comprobante.Descuento = 0
    comprobante.DescuentoSpecified = True
    comprobante.Total = "112.00"
    comprobante.SubTotal = "100.00"
    comprobante.LugarExpedicion = "20000"
    comprobante.Moneda = "MXN"
    comprobante.FormaPago = "03"
    comprobante.FormaPagoSpecified = True
    comprobante.TipoCambio = 1.0
    comprobante.TipoCambioSpecified = True
    comprobante.MetodoPago = "PUE"
    comprobante.MetodoPagoSpecified = True
    comprobante.Exportacion = "01"

    'Llenamos datos del emisor
    Dim Emisor As cfdV40.ComprobanteEmisor = New cfdV40.ComprobanteEmisor()

    Emisor.Rfc = "IIA040805DZ4"
    Emisor.Nombre = "INDUSTRIA ILUMINADORA DE ALMACENES"
    Emisor.RegimenFiscal = "601"

    comprobante.Emisor = Emisor

    'Llena datos del receptor
    Dim Receptor As cfdV40.ComprobanteReceptor = New cfdV40.ComprobanteReceptor()

    Receptor.Rfc = "OIGJ7604112Q0"
    Receptor.Nombre = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape("T'S VALLADOLID")
    'Receptor.Nombre = "T'S VALLADOLID".Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("&amp;", "&")
    Receptor.DomicilioFiscalReceptor = "53100"
    Receptor.RegimenFiscalReceptor = "601"
    Receptor.UsoCFDI = "G01"

    comprobante.Receptor = Receptor

    'Llenamos los conceptos
    Dim conceptos(1) As cfdV40.ComprobanteConcepto

    'Concepto 1
    conceptos(0) = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConcepto()
    conceptos(0).Cantidad = 1
    conceptos(0).Unidad = "No Aplica"
    conceptos(0).ClaveUnidad = "E48"
    conceptos(0).Descripcion = "Servicios transporte de carga"
    conceptos(0).ValorUnitario = "100.00"
    conceptos(0).Importe = "100.00"
    conceptos(0).Descuento = "0.00"
    conceptos(0).DescuentoSpecified = True
    conceptos(0).ClaveProdServ = "78101802"
    conceptos(0).ObjetoImp = "02"

    'Llenamos los impuestos del concepto
    conceptos(0).Impuestos = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConceptoImpuestos()
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConceptoImpuestosTraslado(1) {}
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0) = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConceptoImpuestosTraslado()

    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).Base = "100.00"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).Impuesto = "002"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).TipoFactor = "Tasa"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).Importe = "16.00"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).ImporteSpecified = True
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).TasaOCuota = "0.160000"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Traslados(0).TasaOCuotaSpecified = True

    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConceptoImpuestosRetencion(2) {}
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0) = New cfdV40.ComprobanteConceptoImpuestosRetencion()
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0).Base = "100.00"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0).Impuesto = "002"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0).TipoFactor = "Tasa"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0).Importe = "4.00"
    conceptos(0).Impuestos.Retenciones(0).TasaOCuota = "0.040000"

    'Agregamos conceptos
    comprobante.Conceptos = conceptos

    'LLenamos el nodo impuestos globales
    comprobante.Impuestos = New cfdV40.ComprobanteImpuestos()

    'Impuesto 2
    comprobante.Impuestos.Retenciones = New cfdV40.ComprobanteImpuestosRetencion(2) {}
    comprobante.Impuestos.Retenciones(0) = New cfdV40.ComprobanteImpuestosRetencion()
    comprobante.Impuestos.Retenciones(0).Impuesto = "002"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Retenciones(0).Importe = "4.00"

    'Impuesto 1
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados = New cfdV40.ComprobanteImpuestosTraslado(1) {}
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0) = New cfdV40.ComprobanteImpuestosTraslado()
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).Base = "100.00"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).Impuesto = "002"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).TipoFactor = "Tasa"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).TasaOCuota = "0.160000"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).TasaOCuotaSpecified = True
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).Importe = "16.00"
    comprobante.Impuestos.Traslados(0).ImporteSpecified = True

    comprobante.Impuestos.TotalImpuestosRetenidos = "4.00"
    comprobante.Impuestos.TotalImpuestosTrasladados = "16.00"
    comprobante.Impuestos.TotalImpuestosRetenidosSpecified = True
    comprobante.Impuestos.TotalImpuestosTrasladadosSpecified = True

    Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim xmlNameSpace As XmlSerializerNamespaces = New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
    Dim root As XmlRootAttribute = New XmlRootAttribute()


    root.Namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4"  'Con esto hago que todo tenga "cfdi" en el prefijo
    root.IsNullable = False

    xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    xmlNameSpace.Add("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4")

    Dim xmlTexto As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    xmlTexto.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented

    Dim xss As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(cfdV40.Comprobante), root)
    xss.Serialize(xmlTexto, comprobante, xmlNameSpace)

    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

    stream.Position = 0
    doc.Load(stream)

    Dim attrib As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") 'creo un nuevo atributo 
    attrib.Value = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd" 'asigno el valor del atributo se modifico ya que timbre fiscal lo valida pero el SAT no y marca error al validarlo


    Dim attribXmlns As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:cfdi") 'creo un nuevo atributo 

    attribXmlns.Value = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" 'asigno el valor del atributo

    Dim attribXmlnsInstance As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi") 'creo un nuevo atributo 

    attribXmlnsInstance.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 'asigno el valor del atributo

    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Prepend(attribXmlns) 'agrego el atributo al inicio de la coleccion
    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.InsertAfter(attribXmlnsInstance, attribXmlns) 'agrego el atributo despues del primer atributo
    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.InsertAfter(attrib, attribXmlnsInstance) 'agrego el atributo despues del primer atributo}


    xmlTexto.Close()

    doc.Save("C:\\FacXMLPDF\\PRUEBAS\\SAT\\archivo.xml")

End Sub
```

End Module

Espero poder guardar el xml cuando lleva apostrofe y que quede así T'S VALLADOLID en lugar de como actualmente me lo está generando, actualmente cuando lleva apostrofe queda guardado el xml así T&'S VALLADOLID pero así al tratar de timbrar el documento me lo rechaza porque lleva de más el &amp.

No he encontrado la solución a este detalle.

Saludos y quedó a la espera de sus comentarios.

Agradezco sus sugerencias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En este sitio no se descargan proyecto.. el codigo debe ir en la pregunta. fijate de hacer un [mcve]